# Array data is 'lost' after passing the array to another object

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm having a problem where the objects in my array are lost when I pass the array through a constructor. My first guess was that I needed to change it to an array of pointers but that resulted in a segfault. My next guess was that I needed to copy the array data after passing it but that also didn't work. Here's the problem code:

Universe Object:

```
class Universe {
public: 
    Star stars[]; int starsLength;
    Planet planets[]; int planetsLength;
public: 
    Universe(Star st[], int stl, Planet pl[], int pll) {
        stars < st; starsLength = stl;
        planets < pl; planetsLength = pll;
    }
    Universe() {

    }
public:
    void render() {        
        for(int i = 0;i < starsLength;i++) {
            //std::cout << "STAR: " << stars[i].location.x << "," << stars[i].location.y << " " << stars[i].size << " " << stars[i].color.r << "," << stars[i].color.g << "," << stars[i].color.b << "\n";
            renderCircle(stars[i].location, stars[i].size, stars[i].color);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < planetsLength;i++) {
            renderCircle(planets[i].location, planets[i].size, planets[i].color);
        }
    }
    void renderCircle(Point location, float size, Color color) {
       glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor3f(color.r,color.g,color.b);
            glVertex2f(location.x+size, location.y+size);
            glVertex2f(location.x-size, location.y-size);
            glVertex2f(location.x-size, location.y+size);
            glVertex2f(location.x+size, location.y-size);
       glEnd();
    }
};
```

Method that creates the Universe and gives it the array:

```
Universe buildUniverse(int size, int seed) {
    Point bounds = Point{static_cast <float> (size),static_cast <float> (size)}; //0,0 to size,size
    int starCount = min(size/10,random(size/5));
    int planetCount = min(size/3,random(size));

    Star stars[starCount];
    Planet planets[planetCount];
    //std::cout << "-- Created " << starCount << " stars and " << planetCount << " planets...\n";

    for(int i = 0;i < starCount;i++) {
        Point location = {random(bounds.x),random(bounds.y)};
        Point velocity = {random(bounds.x/100.0f),random(bounds.y/100.0f)};
        float size = random(bounds.x/100.0f);
        float mass = random(size*(random(1.0f)+0.5f));
        Color color = {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
        stars[i].setStar(location,velocity,size,mass,color);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < planetCount;i++) {
        Point location = {random(bounds.x),random(bounds.y)};
        Point velocity = {random(bounds.x/100.0f),random(bounds.y/100.0f)};
        float size = random(bounds.x/100.0f);
        float mass = random(size*(random(1.0f)+0.5f));
        Color color = {random(1.0f),random(1.0f),random(1.0f)};
        planets[i].setPlanet(location,velocity,size,mass,color);
    }

    Universe uni = {stars, starCount, planets, planetCount};
    std::cout << "Star in array: " << stars[0].location.x << "," << stars[0].location.y << " " << stars[0].size << " " << stars[0].color.r << "," << stars[0].color.g << "," << stars[0].color.b << "\n";
    std::cout << "Star passed to uni in an array: " << uni.stars[0].location.x << "," << uni.stars[0].location.y << " " << uni.stars[0].size << " " << uni.stars[0].color.r << "," << uni.stars[0].color.g << "," << uni.stars[0].color.b << "\n";
    return uni;
}
```

Output of of the program:

```
Building universe...
Star in array: 39.922,39.155 0.167611 1,1,8.85715e-39
Star passed to uni in an array: 7.00649e-45,2.24208e-44 0.0282954 5.90446e-39,1.4013e-45,1.4013e-45
Initializing threaded renderer...
Starting simulation...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you are passing arrays by copy rather than by reference?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem. Reference is the & symbol right? I'm not exactly sure how to use it though.

Comment: What is `stars < st` supposed to do?

Comment: That compiles?? (Especially 1st and 3rd member of `Universe`...) Not on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/790f218f52caa091

Comment: @Deduplicator Compiles and runs.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You can't even pass arrays to functions.

Comment: @Scott Hunter - It's supposed to copy the array I thought. I'm guessing that's not right at all now :/

Comment: @newObjekt - What is this: `Star stars[]`?  This isn't C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: In C99, as the last member of a struct, a flexible array member. In C++, just an error, as I commented.

Comment: You should look into using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Have you verified that the arrays get copied *before* the constructor is finished?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, the values are okay in the parameter but after they are copied it turns into garbage data.

Comment: @newObjekt - What is `stars < st;` supposed to do?  Are you making up a new language as you go along?  It doesn't do what you think it does, or using that alien syntax to create arrays, I have no idea what it could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is not valid C++.  Declaring empty arrays using `[]` does not exist in C++.

So the first thing is to turn this into valid C++ that still preserves what you're trying to accomplish.  One solution is to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
class Universe {
public: 
    std::vector<Star> stars;
    std::vector<Planet> planets;
public: 
    Universe(const std::vector<Star>& st, 
             const std::vector<Planet>& pl) : stars(st), planets(pl) {}
};
```

Note the replacement of the non-C++ code with `std::vector`.  Also note that we initialize the vectors using the `initializer-list`.

Last, note that we no longer need to keep the sizes as separate member variables.  Why?  Because a vector knows its size by calling the `vector::size()` member function.  For example:

```
  for(int i = 0;i < starsLength;i++) {
```

can be replaced with

```
  for(int i = 0;i < stars.size();i++) {
```

---

In your `buildUniverse` function, use the following changes:

```
Universe buildUniverse(int size, int seed) {
    Point bounds = Point{static_cast <float> (size),static_cast <float> (size)}; //0,0 to size,size
    int starCount = min(size/10,random(size/5));
    int planetCount = min(size/3,random(size));

    std::vector<Star> stars(starCount);
    std::vector<Planet> planets(planetCount);

    //...
    Universe uni(stars, planets);
```

The rest of the code stays the same.  Now, if after the call to create the `Universe`, you see that the vectors didn't pass the correct information, then look further.  The code above conforms to "normal" C++, such that we can go further and figure out the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to give this a go on Monday. Is there any good reason to use the standard array types over a library like vector? The standard arrays seem very limited.

Comment: C++ standard arrays are fixed in size, while vector isn't fixed in size (it can be resized without any memory management on your part).  Even if you were using fixed size arrays, the `std::array` is a better choice.